What does the following mean in my dad's UK will?


Absolute Residuary Gift
SUBJECT to the trusts DECLARED above my Executors SHALL HOLD my estate for the trustees of THE [name of trust] FAMILY
PROBATE TRUST absolutely



I'm guessing this is England, but note that UK is not a single jurisdiction. That's particularly important for wills.

It means that any property that is left over after, all other distributions called for in the will have been made, go into the THE [name of trust] FAMILY PROBATE TRUST.

Thank you, would you know that as this is a living trust would this then need to go through probate.

@NickLloyd Every will needs to go through probate to have any effect.

Apologies for being a bit vague.  The situation I have and this is in England. My Dad and step mother created a wills and trust in 2013, they created two what they called family probate trusts. I believe the legal term in the uk is a living trust.  I live New Zealand, and so this is a little different to us.

@MichaelHall Probate is literally the process of giving legal effect to a will. To avoid probate you need to use estate planning tools called non-probate transfers other than a will, such as joint tenancies with right of survivorship, life estates, beneficiary designations in accounts, inter vivos trusts, and gifts made during life.

@MichaelHall It hinges on the meaning of the word "will". If the probate process was not involved, it was probably because alternatives to a will were used.

@MichaelHall Non-probate transfers override express provisions in wills. If it was filed with the county, that was probably a probate proceeding.

@MichaelHall Washington State is exceedingly unusual in the common law world in that respect according to the link.
